# Always getting "Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, "even though testng test got executed using "mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml"

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am expecting  count for Total tests, Passed, Failed should show on console.
I am using latest Testng version 7.4.0. and 2.22.0 surefire version.

I have tried every possible solution but didn't work for me.
Please find my code for maven surefire plugin.

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${surefire.suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>    
            <includes>
                <include>*.*</include>
            </includes>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            <reportsDirectory>target/test-report</reportsDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>      
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Please let me know if anyone knows any solution.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?